# JavaScript polling Firebase to check for changes in data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polling

I was having some problem when trying to do a real-time refresh from listening to changes in Firebase using JavaScript. What I tried to do is a chat system. Upon starting a new chat with another user, I will load all the chats between the two users.

```
code
```

My Firebase query:

```
code
```

The problem is the code above does not work in 'real-time'. Real-time as in when user A send to B, without manually refreshing the page to reload the chats, the user B should be able to seethe latest message from user A.

The code above only work if the user B manually refresh the page to query from Firebase again.

Is there something like polling from JavaScript to Firebase to check for changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use `on value` event to automatically get new arrived msg.

Problem is `on value` will return all message value instead of new one.

you need to store timestamp along with msg data,

```
ref.on('value', function(snapshot){

  //request data from firebase that having message-timestamp greater than last message-timestamp in previous `on-value` event

});`
```

To get specific msg, you need to use `firebase query`

```
   var ref= firebase.database().ref("users/msgtimestamp");
   var query = ref.orderByChild('msgtimestamp'); //write query-logic to get only new message
   query.on('value', function(snapshot) {

   });
```

> I hope my answer will help you

Comment: If you want to style differently, you could use a `once()` initially and an `on()` for subsequent changes. But Tuschar's answer shows how to get realtime updates: by using `on(...)` instead of `once(...)`.

Comment: It is depend on you when you have to call `once`, other side `on value` will always call whenever there is change in database on server.

Comment: @TusharAcharekar Yeah but then those code should be wrapped around in a function right? Where do you usually call the function? Because from my loadChatDetail(), I will call the once. Then from there, whenever any updates in the Firebase, I wanted to refresh it. But then if I put the code nested as from the edited portion, it fetched from Firebase the second time after fetching from the once().

Comment: How do you bind all new message to view...? Are you using angular...? I think your problem is in.data binding.....!@hyperfkcb

Comment: Nope I am not using Angular. I am using JavaScript only :)

Comment: Ohhh...i think Your all firebase code is correct but you not able to bind fresh values to your view....That why you need to manual refresh every time....! Whenever you get new value then you have to bind that value to view(in html)....Write JavaScript code to bind values in real time or use simple angular.